# set default working directory for ipython console (terminal)

Tags: ipython

ipython notebook has setting for default working directory

```
c.FileNotebookManager.notebook_dir = '/path/to/my/desired/dir'
```

is there analogous setting for ipython console (terminal) ? I have tried adjusting following configuration parameter:

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.ipython_dir = '/path/to/my/desired/dir'
```

but this seems to have no effect. There is also no comment as to what this parameter is supposed to effect.

How can I configure `ipython` so that my working directory upon start will be  `/path/to/my/desired/dir`, irrespective from where I started `ipython` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your home directory, go to `.ipython`, then your profile directory (probably `profile_default`), then `startup`.   In there, create a new file with the extension `.ipy`,  containing the lines:

```
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/my/desired/dir')
```

As pointed out by [crowie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2290973) in the comments, the `.ipy` extension also enables you to use IPython "magic" commands, so you could instead say:

```
%cd /path/to/my/desired/dir
```

Comment: if using the .ipy extension you can also use any ipython magics or console commands eg: %cd path_to_dir